# Performance of local variable vs. array access

Tags: performance, benchmarking, micro-optimization, perl

I was doing some benchmarking of Perl performance, and ran into a case that I thought was somewhat odd.  Suppose you have a function which uses a value from an array multiple times. In this case, you often see some code as:

```
sub foo {
  my $value = $array[17];

  do_something_with($value);
  do_something_else_with($value);
}
```

The alternative is not to create a local variable at all:

```
sub foo {
  do_something_with($array[17]);
  do_something_else_with($array[17]);
}
```

For readability, the first is clearer.  I assumed that performance would be at least equal (or better) for the first case too - array lookup requires a multiply-and-add, after all.

---

Imagine my surprise when this test program showed the opposite.  On my machine, re-doing the array lookup is actually *faster* than storing the result, until I increase ITERATIONS to 7; in other words, for me, creating a local variable is only worthwhile if it's used at least 7 times!

```
use Benchmark qw(:all);

use constant { ITERATIONS => 4, TIME => -5 };

# sample array
my @array = (1 .. 100);

cmpthese(TIME, {
  # local variable version
  'local_variable' => sub {
    my $index = int(rand(scalar @array));
    my $val = $array[$index];
    my $ret = '';

    for (my $i = 0; $i < ITERATIONS; $i ++) {
       $ret .= $val;
     }

    return $ret;
  },

  # multiple array access version
  'multi_access' => sub {
    my $index = int(rand(scalar @array));
    my $ret = '';

    for (my $i = 0; $i < ITERATIONS; $i ++) {
      $ret .= $array[$index];
    }

    return $ret;
  }
});
```

Result:

```
                   Rate local_variable   multi_access
local_variable 245647/s             --            -5%
multi_access   257907/s             5%             --
```

It's not a HUGE difference, but it brings up my question: **why is it slower to create a local variable and cache the array lookup, than to do the lookup again?**  Reading other S.O. posts, I've seen that other languages / compilers do have the expected outcome, and sometimes even transform these into the same code.  What is Perl doing?

Answer (score 5):

I've done more poking around at this today, and what I've determined is that *scalar **assignment** of any sort* is an expensive operation, relative to the overhead of one-deep array lookup.

This seems like it's just restating the initial question, but I feel I have found more clarity.  If, for example, I modify my local_variable subroutine to do another assignment like so:

```
my $index = int(rand(scalar @array));
my $val = 0; # <- this is new
$val = $array[$index];
my $ret = '';
```

...the code suffers an additional 5% speed penalty beyond the single-assignment version - even though it does nothing but a dummy assignment to the variable.

I also tested to see if scope caused setup/teardown of `$var` to impede performance, by switching it to global instead of local scoped one.  The difference is negligible (see comments to @zdim above), pointing *away* from construct/destruct as the performance bottleneck.

---

In the end, my confusion was based on **faulty assumptions** that **scalar assignment should be fast**.  I am used to working in C, where copying a value to a local variable is an extremely quick operation (1-2 asm instructions).

As it turns out, this is not the case in Perl (though I don't know *exactly* why, it's ok).  Scalar assignment is a relatively "slow" operation... Whatever Perl internals are doing to get at the nth element of an Array object is actually quite fast by comparison.  The "multiply and add" I mentioned in the initial post is still far less work than the code for scalar assignment.

That is why it takes so many lookups to match the performance of caching the result: simply assigning to the "cache" variable is ~7 times slower (for my setup).

Comment: That's an interesting additional analysis. I'd suggest to find what kinds of things a "scalar" has (in perlguts?); it will become immediately clear that it is a bit expensive.  Another good resource are various backends for the module [O](http://perldoc.perl.org/O.html). Try `perl -MO=Concise -e'my $v; $v=1'`. (Also, an assignment is in principle more expensive than a read.)

Comment: Can't help it: This is not C. This is not C. This is not C.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first turn the statement: Caching the lookup is expected to be faster as it avoids the repeated lookups, even as it does cost some, and it starts being faster once more than 7 lookups are done. Now that's not so shocking, I think.

As to why it's slower for fewer than seven iterations ... I'll guess that the cost of the scalar creation is still greater than those few lookups. It is surely greater than one lookup, yes? How about two, then? I'd say that "a few" may well be a good measure.

Comment: But WHY is scalar creation slow?  This is really more of a perlguts question: it's unclear to me why this would be the case.  In C, for example, scalar creation just makes the stack 4 bytes bigger.  There should be no performance difference.  Why does it matter here?  What's the real break-even point?

Comment: @GregKennedy Scalar in Perl is an object (so to speak), with a bunch of properties/fields.  It's at least 12 bytes (I think). Of course that it takes some time to get it up and going.

Comment: It's not just the SV (internal storage of the scalar value), it also has to create that SV scoped to that lexical block and tear it down at the end. Without having to create that SV the compiler is possibly optimizing away that scope entirely, I know it does this with simpler blocks at least. I see that your benchmarks are more complex though so probably not that.

Comment: I tried two things for another test: replacing ITERATIONS constant with a loop (so I can see the switch-over point), and adding another version that updates a global variable instead of defining it in local. Global is marginally faster than Local, but neither is faster than direct array access until ~7 iterations.  The results are here: https://pastebin.com/cTEZZe18

Comment: @GregKennedy This is all interesting but I don't think that such detailed and precise benchmarks can be reliable down to counting single iterations. I get similar behavior and the number at which it turns around is about what you quote -- but fluctuates a lot between runs. This isn't C and there are too many random factors in each run of the interpreter.   Altogether, yes a scalar is expensive (comparatively speaking of data.

Comment: @GregKennedy  Btw, note that in an array each element needs a full-blown scalar constructed as well (on top of constructing the array "object" itself).  The total size of the array is two to three times the size of its data. There is even more to do for a hash, which is bigger and slower than an array.  These things cost in Perl, as something has to pay for all the conveniences.